# Why my printf does not work?

Tags: c, numbers

The question is to find the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143, and my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    float i,x;
    float a,y;
    for(a=2;a<=600851475143;a++)
    {
        y=fmod(600851475143,a);
        if(y==0)
        {
            int sum=0;
            for(i=2;i<=a/2;i++)
            {
                if(fmod(a,i)==0)
                {
                    sum=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(sum==0&&a>x)
            x=a;
            // printf("%f\n",x );
        }

    }
    printf("%f\n",x );
    return 0;
}
```

Why is my printf function not working? When I put printf above (shown in comments), it works, but the last printf does not work. Why?

Comment: try to initialize `x=0` at first and then check whether it prints or not

Comment: Your number will not be represented with sufficient  precision as float. Need double or long long.

Comment: still does't working

Comment: but it is working in the commented printf

Comment: 600,851,475,143 is a huge number, your loop won't finish on a super computer. That's why you can't see the last printf as the program is still looping. If 'a' doesn't overflow before that, then ti will never finish.

Comment: Are you sure that your commented printf is working and the last printf is not printing any value. Because you can see you have used break statement, this will kick you out from for loop when the if condition matched. Try printing some other value with the integer in print statement.

Comment: yes works for smaller number

Comment: and the commented printf works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `printf` function have problem, when you run the program, it needs too much time, so the last printf didn't run, you should choose another faster algorithm for optimization.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    float i,x;
    float a,y;
    for(a=2;a<=600851475143;a++) // it needs too much time!
    {
        y=fmod(600851475143,a);
        if(y==0)
        {
            int sum=0;
            for(i=2;i<=a/2;i++)  // this algorithm is O(N^2)
            {
                if(fmod(a,i)==0)
                    {
                        sum=1;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            if(sum==0&&a>x)
            x=a;
            printf("%f\n",x );
        }
    }
    printf("%f\n",x ); // needs too much time to go here
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
long double i,x, a, y;
    for(a=2;a<=600851475143;a++)
    {
        y=fmod(600851475143,a);
        if(y==0)
        {
            int sum=0;
            for(i=2;i<=a/2;i++)
            {
                if(fmod(a,i)==0)
                    {
                        sum=1;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            if(sum==0&&a>x)
            x=a;
            printf("%Lf\n",x );
            //break;
            }

  }
printf("%Lf\n",x );
return 0;
}
```

if there is no break it will find a number at a condition but will return to the for and keep looking for another. That is why you use a break to find the first one. To find more I recommend using "long double" data type.

which is a Real floating-point type, usually mapped to an extended precision floating-point number format. Actual properties unspecified. Unlike types float and double, it can be either 80-bit floating point format, the non-IEEE "double-double" or IEEE 754 quadruple-precision floating-point format if a higher precision format is provided, otherwise it is the same as double.

Comment: but if there is break we can't able to find the maximum value